# Why is the maximum value of a column never equal to or greater than 10?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

In my application I have table  name is **dataset_master**. 
And Table has field name is **dataset_id**, I want to get maximum value of this field so simple I fire following Query with code.

```
-(NSString *) getLastRowFromDataset_masterTableByProjectID:(NSString *) project_id
{
    NSString *dataset_id = @"";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT MAX(dataset_id) FROM dataset_master where project_id = ?;"];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [project_id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            char *datasetIDChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);

            if(datasetIDChars != NULL)
                dataset_id  = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:datasetIDChars];

        }
    }

    return dataset_id;
}
```

Here `project_id` is require for me because I need to get `dataset_id` base on `project_id`.

All is well but when `dataset_id` is **10 or more then 10** then I can not get proper maximum value, i mean each time i get **9**.

I don't know what is real problem I simple fire Query but I can not get proper answer.

Comment: is this sqlite?  What do you get from the sqlite cmd line?  What code is executing this?

Comment: yes its SQlLite,, i can not got any error message

Comment: What do you get from sqlite cmd line?  Include code calling that query.

Comment: @bryanmac- check my full method of code :)

Comment: You must be using varchar field. Instead either convert it to an integer or do casting inside max function

Comment: You must be using varchar field. Instead either convert it to an integer or do casting inside max function <br> try inserting a value 95 in your table and see the result

Comment: Can you specify the datatype for dataset_id and project_id?

Comment: @SushmaSatish- both are 'TEXT'..

Comment: You need to make the column numeric rather than text.

Comment: Just change the CREATE TABLE statement to make the column INTEGER instead of TEXT.  (Be sure to delete the app from the simulator so that the table will be recreated.)

Comment: And study the most excellent SQLite documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html.

Comment: @Ranju, casting @ query time is not the right solution - making the id an int is the "right" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query but be aware this is a bit **costly** call:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT MAX(CAST(dataset_id AS INTEGER)) FROM dataset_master where project_id = ?;"];
```

Else

Changing datatype of dataset_id to integer should solve your issue.

*For Ranju Patel's query:*

- **Why MAX function would not work with TEXT datatype?**

In case of TEXT datatype, the sorting order would be ASCII sorting order,

where in **"9" > "10"**, **"09" < "10"**, [Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Order], Hence the MAX function would not work if the data stored is "9", "10".

on the other hand,

if the data sotred is "09", "10", and your query is:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT MAX(dataset_id) FROM dataset_master where project_id = ?;"];
```

the result you would get is "10".

- **Would my answer be valid for long time?**

It would work if you don't have too many data, else it would slow you down, Hence I have mentioned it as: its very costly to call **CAST** function in the raw SELECT query.

Comment: wow yar its work for me ..thank for your golden help.. but you can explain me why its not work with TEXT datatype and are you sure that your answer is not bad for long time ?? thanks again :)

Comment: This is a workaround for the real issue.  The real issue is ids should be ints.  It works around the issue by casting each string to to ints @ query time.  This is not efficient for storage, indexes etc...  Make the storage an int and save the casting etc...

Comment: bryanmac, I agree with you thats why I have mentioned its costly to do this. I too agree with you that id fields should be of type integer.

Comment: @SushmaSatish- thanks for your elaborate your answer :) but if the data sotred is "09", "10", and your query is:....the result you would get is "10"... but each time i got 9 not 10,, and why my previous query is properly works for 1 to 9 'dataset_id' ? and not when i have `dataset_id` 10 or more then 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a text field "9" will be greater than "10".  For an id field you should use an integer to get good comparisons.

Then you can retrieve it with something like:

```
NSNumber *id = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:sqlite_column_int64(statement, i)];
```

When you [create the sqlite table](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), use an INTEGER column and not TEXT.  Better yet, you can define the column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and it will return the rowid of the table.  More can be read [here under ROWIDs and INTEGER PIMARY KEYS heading](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).  Since it's an alias for the rowid, you shouldn't need to assign a value when inserting data - it will get the next highest id.

If you do not want this column to be a unique id, then simply define the column as an integer and supply a value when inserting.

Finally, if you're trying to get the max id, consider using [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) after inserting.  It will return the last id from the rowid.

Comment: please elaborate you answer , i can't got it because i am new at iOS development.. and my dataset_id is 'TEXT' so what i need to change ?

Comment: here my dataset_id is not auto_inc. it is simple field .. then also i need to apply 'integer' instead of TEXT ?

Comment: But sqlite3_last_insert_rowid it will return last inserted row id from whole database but i need to get it only from table not in whole database ..

Comment: It sounds like an id so I would recommend integer primary key.  If it's not a unique id, then define as integer and assign yourself.  But then you lose capabilities like last insert rowid function and auto assign ...

Comment: For last row id, that's why I said use it after the insert.  If that's not your scenario, then select max will also work.

Comment: Thanks for your golden help.. i wil try it , so finally i need to change my field dataset_id with its type "INTEGER" instead of "TEXT" "??